# Is it possible to use high order functions to amalgamate duplicate objects in an array?

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I have an array of objects, each object has a name and a quantity. I want to scan through the array and if any objects have the same name, to reduce to one single object with the total quantity of all those objects that have been merged.

```
struct AnObject {
    var name: String
    var quantity: UInt
}

var anArray = [AnObject(name: "one", quantity: 2),
                AnObject(name: "two", quantity: 2),
                AnObject(name: "one", quantity: 2),
                AnObject(name: "one", quantity: 2),
                AnObject(name: "two", quantity: 2)]

// something like:     
return reduce(anArray,(),{ /* some magic */})

// should return [{"one":6},{"two",4}]
```

This can be done using a cumbersome for loop creating a new array but is there a more 'functional' way of doing it with high order functions like .filter, .reduce or even .map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` method to transform the array into a dictionary, having the name as key and the array element as value, and populate/update accordingly:

```
// Pass an empty dictionary as initial value
anArray.reduce([String:AnObject]()) {
    // The initial value parameter is immutable, so make a mutable copy
    var dict = $0

    if dict[$1.name] != nil {
        // If the key already exists, update the quantity
        dict[$1.name]?.quantity += $1.quantity
    } else {
        // Otherwise add the element
        dict[$1.name] = $1
    }

    return dict
}.values.array
```

The last line takes the `values` collection and convert it into an array.

To note that without compiler optimizations this solution is not efficient, but adherent to the functional philosophy. The reason for the inefficiency is that a new dictionary is created at each iteration. However I think that the compiler is able to optimize the process by avoiding actual copies - although it's better to measure the execution time and compare with the performance of a traditional loop based solution to be sure if and how a solution is better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var compressed = [String:UInt]()
for obj in anArray as [AnObject] {
  let name = obj.name
  let val = compressed[name] ?? 0
  compressed[name] = obj.quantity + val
}
var res = [AnObject]()
for (key, val) in compressed {
  res.append(AnObject(name:key, quantity:val))
}
res
```

Comment: It's a great answer but not for the question I asked :-)

Comment: You can create an extension which then behaves like `.filter`. But inside you need those loops.

Comment: @DanielCreagh Why's that?  Given your `anObject` type and `anArray` data set, @ThomasKilian's solution gives the exact same result as @Antonio's: http://imgur.com/a/newNP

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find` by implementing `Equatable`:

```
struct AnObject: Equatable {
  var name: String
  var quantity: UInt
}
func ==(lhs: AnObject, rhs: AnObject) -> Bool {
  return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
anArray = anArray.reduce([AnObject]()) {
  var array:[AnObject] = $0
  if let a = find(array, $1) {
    array[a].quantity += $1.quantity
  } else {
    array.append($1)
  }
  return array
}
```